# How can I display format-table powershell data imported from csv with an if statement?

Tags: powershell, csv, azure, format, office365

I'm trying to automate some Office 365 user creation stuff and am getting stuck on a simple formatting syntax for displaying values that will be changing.  This piece of code searches for any users with a null value for the Usage Location field in Azure's directory and stores them into a file (which is used multiple times later, and I'd like to keep it in a file for archiving purposes as well)... All I want to display to the user running the script is a simple table with Firstname, Lastname, and UPN... (not sam, needs to be UPN see the subdomain value).  But the results will only be processed if the UPN contains "@STU.DOMAIN.COM" ... Here's what I have right now:

```
    Get-MsolUser -MaxResults 4000 | Where {$_.usagelocation -eq $null}| Export-Csv C:\Test.csv
    Import-CSV C:\Test.csv | ForEach-Object {
           $fname= $_.FirstName
           $lname= $_.LastName
           $UPN= $_.UserPrincipalName
           if ($UPN.Contains("@STU.DOMAIN.COM")) {
                New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property @{
                "User Principal Name" = $UPN
                "Last Name" = $lname
                "First Name" = $fname
                }
           } 
    }
```

I have no real idea why, but it works when I run the tiny part of code here in an ISE window, but it does not work in a normal powershell window while I'm connected to MSOL and the rest of the script is in play...?  I guess I'm looking for someone with actual experience to show me the proper way to format this task... Anyone got some wisdom to share please?

Thanks!

---

Update:
Hi Frode - this doesn't appear to separate them into groups.  The "User Principal Name" variable is their whole username@UPN so it doesn't group it by domain and subdomain.  The output looks like this:

```
       User Principal Name: User1@DOMAIN.COM

    First Name Last Name User Principal Name
    ---------- --------- -------------------
    User1      Last1     User1@DOMAIN.COM   


       User Principal Name: User2@STU.DOMAIN.COM

    First Name Last Name User Principal Name
    ---------- --------- -------------------
    User2      Last2     User2@STU.DOMAIN.COM
```

How do I get just the @STU.DOMAIN.COM or @DOMAIN.COM of the variable to sort by?

Update 2:
I managed to figure out a way to strip off the suffix of the UPN and display that, but it still is quirky.  It lists clumps of users of different UPNs randomly... Here's the code I modified from Frode:

```
    $users |
    Select-Object @{n="First Name";e={$_.FirstName}}, @{n="Last Name";e={$_.LastName}}, @{n="Domain/UPN";e={$_.UserPrincipalName.split("@")[1]}} |
    Format-Table -AutoSize -GroupBy "Domain/UPN" | Out-String | Write-Host
```

But the output is a bit weird... it looks like this:

```
       Domain/UPN: STU.DOMAIN.COM

    First Name Last Name Domain/UPN    
    ---------- --------- ----------    
    Dede       Lastname  STU.DOMAIN.COM


       Domain/UPN: DOMAIN.COM

    First Name Last Name    Domain/UPN
    ---------- ---------    ----------
    Thomas     Lastname     DOMAIN.COM
    Wells      Lastname     DOMAIN.COM
    Amy        Lastname     DOMAIN.COM
    Tiffany    Lastname     DOMAIN.COM
    Sara       Lastname     DOMAIN.COM
    Amy        Lastname     DOMAIN.COM


       Domain/UPN: STU.DOMAIN.COM

    First Name Last Name Domain/UPN    
    ---------- --------- ----------    
    Jair       Lastname  STU.DOMAIN.COM


       Domain/UPN: DOMAIN.COM

    First Name Last Name      Domain/UPN
    ---------- ---------      ----------
    Cathy      Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Paul       Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Ridgewood  Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Patty      Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Linda      Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Chris      Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Cami       Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Kent       Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Michael    Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Stephanie  Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Amie       Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Patrick    Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    LaVonne    Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    De         Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Joann      Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Chuck      Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Kathy      Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Sue        Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Tech       Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Theresa    Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Kristin    Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Toni       Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
    Sabrina    Lastname       DOMAIN.COM
```

Is there a method to parse them and group them together in one big lump by domain/UPN suffix?

Thanks again in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest trying this approach, which removes the if test, reimporting of data etc.

```
#Store result
$users = Get-MsolUser -MaxResults 4000 | Where-Object {$_.usagelocation -eq $null}
#Export to csv for later use
$users | Export-Csv C:\Test.csv

#Display users with UPN
$users |
Where-Object { $_.UserPrincipalName -match '@STU\.DOMAIN\.COM' } |
Select-Object @{n="First Name";e={$_.FirstName}}, @{n="Last Name";e={$_.LastName}}, @{n="User Principal Name";e={$_.UserPrincipalName}} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String | Write-Host
```

To group by UPN, try:

```
$users |
Select-Object @{n="First Name";e={$_.FirstName}}, @{n="Last Name";e={$_.LastName}}, @{n="Domain/UPN";e={$_.UserPrincipalName.split("@")[1]}} |
Sort-Object "Domain/UPN" |
Format-Table -AutoSize -GroupBy "Domain/UPN" | Out-String | Write-Host
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - when running this snippet of code it works like a champ... however, when I put it within my script containing the rest of the code, it still does not display anything on the screen.  If I put a simple value like $UPN, that shows up normally, it just seems it won't display the format in a table for some reason... any reason for that?

Comment: And yes, the CSV has data - that's working properly - just nothing gets displayed on the screen.  UPN matches properly.

Comment: Try updated answer. I need to see the rest of the script to find the problem. What I think is wrong, is that the rest of your script catches the object that `select-object` returned. So the updated answer pipes it to `Write-Host` to make sure that the objects is displayed.

Comment: Just curious though - is there a way to group it by UPN?  So perhaps I could run this same script but instead of just showing the stu.domain.com UPN, it would display the domain.com users as well as stu.domain.com users but seperating them into groups?

Comment: I got the suffix stripped off and usable now - but seems to clump the users into different groups as it parses the list... is there a way to parse the whole list and display all users in one domain first, then show the other subdomain?  Example provided in original post.

Comment: Try sorting by domain first to group the pipeline-stream before displaying the result. See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect!!  Works like a champ!  Great support Frode F.  Thanks so much.

Comment: +1 :) Also, from the comments and your question to judge by, it looks like your parent script somehow catches the output objects from this script. Using `Out-String | Write-Host` is the proper way to output visual-only data, but it's still a workaround. You should find the original "bug" that stored or threw away the objects in your parent script, just to avoid that it causes other problems later. :)